# Defective Chips, Why not use nCk?

Tags: probability, combinations, percentages

Below is an example that I understand the solution to, but not why the problem should be approached using percentages versus n chose k.

---

**Example 1 from [Khan Academy](https://www.khanacademy.org/math/ap-statistics/probability-ap/probability-multiplication-rule/a/probabilities-involving-at-least-one-success)**

A manufacturer of processing chips knows that 2%, percent of its chips are defective in some way.
Suppose an inspector randomly selects 4 chips for an inspection.
Assuming the chips are independent, what is the probability that at least one of the selected chips is defective?

P(defective)=0.02 and P(not defective)=0.98, thus

P(No defective if 4 chosen) = 0.98^4 = 0.922

P(at least one defective) = 1 - 0.922 = 0.078

---

What is wrong with using "nCk" (n choose k) to solve this problem? How would this problem change if the tested concept was meant to be "nCk".

Comment: How do you propose to use nCk?  It would come in if you chose $n$ chips and wanted the probability that $k$ were defective.

Comment: (nCk(2,0)*nCk(98,4))/nCk(100,4) and

(nCk(2,1)*nCk(98,3))/nCk(100,4)?

But I just guessed and checked to approach these values. Is there a counter example when percentages vs nCk is better to use? Or in general can we always approach a problem with nCk and percentages?

Comment: $\binom{2}{0}$ is used when you have 2 things and want to choose 0 of them. $\binom{98}{4}$ is for when you have 98 things and want to choose 4 of them. Can you explain which zero things you wanted to choose from four in the first case, or which 98 things you were choosing from in the second? It's not clear how you came up with that expression.

Comment: assuming a full percent is considered an object the first could represent having chosen 0 from the 2 percent defective, and 4 from the 98 percent not defective it would assume a full batch is 100 though @A_P or scalable from 100.

Comment: @RoddyMacPhee I still don't see what sense it makes. Have you ever seen discrete objects called "percent defective(s)" that you had to choose combinations of?

Comment: I never said it makes sense ( but factorial can be extended to gamma which would work out more precisely). it does actually give the correct value roughly.

Comment: @RoddyMacPhee Ah, I see what you mean now. Thanks for clarifying.

Answer (score 0):

Let $X$ be the number of defective chips among the four.
\begin{align}
\Pr(X\ge1) = {} & \Pr(X=1) + \Pr(X=2) + \Pr(X=3) + \Pr(X=4) \\[12pt]
= {} & {}_4C_1 \,\,0.98^1(1-0.98)^3 + {}_4C_2\,\,0.98^2(1-0.98)^2 \\[2pt]
& {} + {}_4C_3 \,\,0.98^3(1-0.98)^1 + {}_4C_4 \,\,0.98^4 \\[12pt]
= {} & 4\cdot0.98^1(1-0.98)^3 + 6\cdot0.98^2(1-0.98)^2 \\[2pt]
& {} + 4\cdot0.98^3(1-0.98) + 0.98^4.
\end{align}
That is perfectly valid. One can also proceed as follows:
$$
\Pr(X\ge 1) = 1 - \Pr(X=0) = 1 - 0.98^4.
$$
The second way is more efficient, especially if, for example, we had $60$ instead of $4.$

Comment: is there a distribution name for this sort of problem?